# How to use mysql dump with django?

Tags: mysql, django

I am new to both django and mysql, I am given a mysql dump file that will be used in a django app. I created a new database and restored the dump file into that using mysqldump. Now I am lost about how to use both of them together. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any models set up? `inspectdb` can be used to create models from existing tables https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have restored the dump on to your database.

Make django migrations

`python manage.py makemigrations`

Fake the migrations

`python manage.py migrate --fake`

Run the app

`python manage.py runserver`

On a side note, you can **check if you have database credentials on in your settings.py** of your application

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```